Upgrade webpack 4 to 5 in react js
I have a react app with Webpack 4.19.1 and want to update it to 5.97.1. I have the following dependencies in my package.json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.7",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.2",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "sass": "^1.37.5",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"
  }

Now whenever I try to update any dependency and check the dependency tree the packages are incompatible. Is there a way to change the Webpack version with the above dependencies in the project?

